# D-Wave Cloud Service - Pricing for Academic Research Project

Tags: d-wave, research

In D-wave's web portal, I found 3 different ways that one can gain access to more QPU/Hybrid Solver time. One of them is the academic research project. Does anyone here have experience of carrying out such project? And if yes, could you explain how it worked?

Answer (score 1):

When I used their Leap service it was semi-free. When I opened an account they gave me 1 minute of QPU time and unlimited usage of all other offline libraries and D-Wave solvers. I also linked the project repo, this gave me another free minute per month of QPU time.

To not waste QPU time, I first configured everything classically and executed problems on CPUs. And only when I knew that I can't improve on classical configurations/settings I relaunched jobs on Hybrid (CPU + QPU) or just QPU. This was when the counter started ticking.

If your goal is to do some sort of benchmarking on some "standard problems" then definitely one free minute will not be even nearly enough.

I suggest to contact D-Wave directly.

Answer (score 1):

There are two level of free access. For the basic level just sign for the Leap and GitHub (you have to link your Leap account with GitHub one). This allows you for one minute of computational time on QPU and 20 minutes of the time on hybrid solver. Remember however that hybrid solver also uses QPU time, although only 20 ms are on average consumed per one simulation. You can use the Leap account for one month.

Second level is called *Developer*. It has basically the same features as described above, however, each month your available computational time is renewed. But any code you develop under your account has to be ultimately published on GitHub as a public domain.